# AJAX returns response but does not attach the HTML code from response to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**[html](/questions/tagged/html):**

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="unu" id="unu">
<input type="text" name="doi" id="doi">
<button type="button" onclick="check()">OK</button>
</form>
<div id="show_panels"></div>
```

**[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):**

```
function check() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "2.php",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function(result) {
      $('#show_panels').html(result);
    },
    error: function(result) {
      console.log("Eroare:");
      console.log(result);
    }
  });

  var result_input = document.getElementById('result');
  console.log(result_input.value);
}
```

**[php](/questions/tagged/php):**

```
<?php 
$var_unu = $_POST['unu'];
$var_doi = $_POST['doi'];
$rezultat = $var_unu + $var_doi;
?>
<input type='text' value='<?php echo $rezultat ?>' id='result'/>
```

As you can see, I am trying to get in my console (for testing), the value from returned input with `id` result, but console return:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`.

In page source I don`t have the [html](/questions/tagged/html)code for my [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)returned input.
What I do wrong?

**Browser view:**

[image]

**View page source:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the HTML `input` **`result`** exists after the `success` callback is executed.

Try with this:

```
function check() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "2.php",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function(result) {
      $('#show_panels').html(result);

      var result_input = document.getElementById('result');
      console.log(result_input.value);
    },
    error: function(result) {
      console.log("Eroare:");
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
}
```

*Thanks @Titus for the correction.*

---

**Update:**

If you need to reuse the returned value you need some changes:

[html](/questions/tagged/html): Add the HTML `input` **`result`** in the form.

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="unu" id="unu">
  <input type="text" name="doi" id="doi">
  <button type="button" onclick="check()">OK</button>
  <input type="text" value="" id="result" />
</form>
<div id="show_panels"></div>
```

**[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):** Prints the returned value in the HTML `input` **`result`**.

```
function check() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "2.php",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function(result) {
      $('#show_panels').html(result);

      document.getElementById('result').value = result;
    },
    error: function(result) {
      console.log("Eroare:");
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
}
```

**[php](/questions/tagged/php):** In the PHP file, just return the `$rezultat` by using `echo`.

```
<?php 
$var_unu = $_POST['unu'];
$var_doi = $_POST['doi'];
$rezultat = $var_unu + $var_doi;
echo $rezultat;
?>
```

Comment: And what if I have a second Ajax which uses the input result returned from first ajax? I would write an ajax into an ajax? I need my second ajax to get the input value returned in first ajax.

Comment: You are directly returning an HTML `input` from PHP. It would be better to just return a `single value` and assign it to the HTML `input`. Then, you can reuse its value at any other time.